# High rank elliptic curves with prime conductor

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

What is the elliptic curve of prime conductor with the highest rank known ? I have some difficulties finding even one information about it. Also, are such high rank curves "harder" to build than those of composite conductor ? If so, why ?

Comment: One can find some lower bounds (and a wealth of other information) at LMFDB: [here's a list](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?conductor_type=prime&rank=5&search_type=List) of elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ with prime conductor and rank 5, the highest rank included in their database.

Comment: Is it a random question or is there a good reason to ask it?

Comment: It is related to a search on elliptic curves with prime conductor I am pursuing. @reuns

Comment: Very often, LMFDB has not the highest rank known curves this is why I am asking @KReiser

Comment: Thanks for the info, I don't spend much time thinking about this so I wasn't fully aware. I would like to point out that you might have saved me telling you things you already know if you had included a little more information in your post - something like "here's what I know and where I've checked so far" would be a good example.